# How do I prevent spaces from being URL encoded for a `javascript:` URL?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the following as a URL that executes javascript:

```
javascript:var field = document.getElementsByName("actions[hide]"); + for (i = 0; i &lt; field.length; i++)field[i].click();
```

However, the spaces get URL encoded when I bookmark it, replaced with `%20`, which (for a reason unknown to me) causes the JS code not to work.

```
javascript:var%20field%20=%20unescape%20document.getElementsByName("actions[hide]");%20+%20for%20(i%20=%200;%20i%20&lt;%20field.length;%20i++)field[i].click();
```

Comment: The `javascript:` URL scheme is a bad idea. Use a normal URL, and bind the "click" handler so it [degrades gracefully](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript#Degrading_gracefully).

Comment: What, exactly, are you [trying to do](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal)? Are you trying to create a bookmarklet? If so, what is it for?

Comment: @outis, have you read the question or only edited it? It is a bookmark(let).

Comment: @kirilloid: the original question was nearly impossible to understand. Rather than guessing, I want Marco to clarify.

Comment: yes creating bookmarklet , this script do mass ignore all facebook request at once , i got alot of request need to mass ignore not go one by one

Comment: @MarcoDz: please update the question with the requested information. In general, respond to requests for clarifications by updating your post, rather than replying with a comment. For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to create a bookmarklet i would suggest you this site:

http://benalman.com/code/test/jquery-run-code-bookmarklet/

there is written that it is used for jquery code but you can also convert normal javascript with this generator. Or you can simplify use the jquery and convert your code from:

```
var field = document.getElementsByName("actions[hide]"); + for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++)field[i].click();
```

to

```
$('[name="actions[hide]"]').each(function() { $(this).click(); });
```

i use this script every time i create a new bookmarklet and i love it

EDIT: when you enter your code you must paste it without the "javascript:" text in front.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand as well the purpose you mean for that javascript as url scheme.
Anyway if you put that string into the browse address bar to work within the current web page, probably it won't.
You can try to call an anonymous function:

```
<a href="javascript:(function() { var field = document.getElementsByName('actions[hide]'); for (var i = 0; i < field.length; i++) { field[i].click(); } })();">Click me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Encoding spaces in javascript: URIs shouldn't (and doesn't in my experience) break scripts. The problem is most likely your `+` which is also a special character in URIs (it also means a space) but isn't being automatically converted by the browser as the character is allowed at that point in a URI.

You need to encode the `+` character as `%2B` (along with any other special characters you might have in the JS).